# return input number for which equation is closest to zero

Tags: python, range, output, equation

I'm trying to input a range of values to an equation, and then return the input value for which the *equation* is closest to zero.  Currently I have:

```
def function():
    bestNumber = 10000000000 #an obscenely large number to start from
    for input in range(15):
        pos = 2 * (10**10.5)/(10**10.5+10**input)
        neg = 2 * (10**3.86)/(10**3.86+10**input)
        finalNumber = pos - neg
        if finalNumber < bestNumber:
            bestNumber = finalNumber
    print (bestNumber)
    print (input)
function()

>>>0.0002760
>>>14
```

Of course, this function will always print a number pretty close to `0`, but simply prints the last value in the loop.

I am really struggling to find a way to to return the `input` value that results in the *lowest* value of `bestNumber`.  I feel like I am pretty close but am missing some key knowledge of loops.

Answer (score 2):

**First:** just have your function to calculate your value for you, given the input -

```
def function(input):
    pos = 2 * (10**10.5)/(10**10.5+10**input)
    neg = 2 * (10**3.86)/(10**3.86+10**input)
    return pos - neg
```

**Second:** you can use a [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions) (technically a generator expression, here) to generate your values, and pass that to the builtin `min` function -

```
bestNumber, input = min((function(i), i) for i in range(15))
# (0.00027603868572034784, 0)
```

Answer (score 1):

You could just add another variable that keeps track of the associated best input:

```
def function():
    bestNumber = 10000000000 #an obscenely large number to start from
    bestInput = 0
    for input in range(0,15):
        pos = 2 * (10**10.5)/(10**10.5+10**input)
        neg = 2 * (10**3.86)/(10**3.86+10**input)
        finalNumber = pos - neg
        if finalNumber < bestNumber:
            bestNumber = finalNumber
            bestInput = input
    return (bestInput, bestNumber)

bestIn, bestNum = function()
print(bestIn)
print(bestNum)

>>>0
>>>0.00027603868572034784
```

EDIT:
This doesn't check decimal numbers, range returns a list of integers. You could do something like this:

```
def function():
    bestNumber = 10000000000 #an obscenely large number to start from
    bestInput = 0
    input = 0
    while (input < 15):
        pos = 2 * (10**10.5)/(10**10.5+10**input)
        neg = 2 * (10**3.86)/(10**3.86+10**input)
        finalNumber = pos - neg
        if finalNumber < bestNumber:
            bestNumber = finalNumber
            bestInput = input
        input = input + 0.1
    return (bestInput, bestNumber)

bestIn, bestNum = function()
print(bestIn)
print(bestNum)

>>>14.999999999999963
>>>6.324353877789737e-05
```

Check a graph of your function, the minimum values are near 0 or 15.

Comment: This looks very promising, but the best input is not 0, it's ~6.8, so something isn't quite right.  In this code, bestInput seems to simply be taking the smallest value in the range

Comment: @rgadra - List comprehensions use extra memory because they create the whole list beforehand, but generator expressions **do not.** And in this case, my formulation is about 8x faster than yours according to `timeit`; please don't make incorrect and untested assertions about performance.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of starting with a huge `bestNumber` value, you could store the first `finalNumber` value during the first iteration of the loop.

Then use that `bestNumber` to compare for the following iterations:

```
def function():
    for input in range(15):
        pos = 2 * (10**10.5)/(10**10.5+10**input)
        neg = 2 * (10**3.86)/(10**3.86+10**input)
        finalNumber = pos - neg
        if input==0:  
            bestNumber=finalNumber         #store bestNumber for the first iteration
        elif finalNumber < bestNumber:     #compare bestNumber for following iterations
            bestNumber = finalNumber
    print (bestNumber)
    print (input)
function()
```

---

```
>>> 
0.00027603868572
14
```